# How to click on href link with image on Html 5 video overlay fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I have added a text overlay with href link, its working with html5 video, but when i switch video in fullscreen mode, href link is not working, I can see the text(ui) in the fullscreen mode video, but unable to click.can anyone help me?
 [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zyaztxa/)

```
  <video id="v" controls>
    <source id='mp4'
    src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
    type='video/mp4'>
    <source id='webm'
    src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
    type='video/webm'>
    <source id='ogv'
    src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
    type='video/ogg'>
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>


  </video>
  <div id="overlay">
  <a href="https://google.com">This is HTML overlay on top of the video! </a></div>
```

thanks

Comment: refer https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/dnvoE

Comment: thanks, its working

Comment: Great, You are welcome!